# TRIGGERS SQL: INSERT OR UPDATE In A Table that is Connected to Another Table

Tags: sql, function, triggers, schema, plpgsql

I have this table called Teacher and School. I would like to create a trigger on the Teacher table to check and disallow any insert or update of a person in the Teacher table to be a teacher of more than one school. Schemas of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE School (
  ID      char(3) primary key,
  Name    text not null,
  Address text default null,
);

CREATE TABLE Teacher (
  ID         char(3) references School(ID),
  Teacher_ID char(5)
  Name       text,
  primary key (ID, Teacher_ID)
);
```

I'm fairly new to trigger and would like to get a better understanding on this problem. Does this mean I have to create two triggers: one for INSERT and another one for UPDATE? Do I have to create a VIEW to help count if the person is already a teacher of a school? This is what I got so far, still empty, messy and wrong but would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me explain parts by parts.

```
create or replace function
    insertPerson() returns trigger
as $$
declare
    t Teacher;
begin
    select * into t from Teacher where ID = new.Teacher_ID;
    update Teacher
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_teacher_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON teacher
    FOR EACH ROW execute procedure insertPerson();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by creating a Unique index on Teacher_ID on Teacher table.